# "Aw, Snap!" why doesn't chrome work?

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome

I'm trying to use Chrome 17 beta, but it doesn't seem to work.  I tried to follow the instructions from the [Google Chrome Help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95669) but to no avail.

I can't even open my settings screen, I get the same "Aw, Snap!" screen.
[image: What my screen looks like]

My question is: How can I diagnose whats going on?  What step can I take to fix it?

I should mention that Firefox still works fine.

Comment: Any event log entries that could assist?

Comment: @DaveM Where would I find them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the "Aw, Snap" dialogue](https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue)

Answer (score 3):

This is why it's called "beta" :) These things sometimes happen. Try completely removing chrome, and then after verifying chrome is completely gone from your system re-installing an RTM (non-beta) version. Verify that the RTM edition works.

If the RTM version works, re-download and re-install the beta. This time, make sure to allow any of the options in the installer that will allow google to gather customer experience data, because you may have found a real bug in the beta. The problem may recur and this will help Google fix it.  Or the problem may not recur, in which case everyone wins.

You might also be able to fix this with a simple update... but again, as you are on the beta channel I'd urge you to re-install with the option to report problems, because it's still likely that this is the result of a bug you somehow stumbled into that may otherwise go unreported (and unfixed).

Comment: Google Chrome manually updates.  It hasn't updated for about a month or so, and I've used it in the last month without any problems.

Comment: But you're still in the beta channel... this just makes the bug harder to reproduce, which would make any data you could provide even more helpful. Of course, it could also be an extension or an early warning sign of a failing hard drive.

Comment: Thanks, I updated Chrome, and the problem went away (add that to your answer if you want the rep).