# How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the "Aw, Snap" dialogue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, memory-error

Does anybody know if there is a practical way to determine the cause of the "Aw Snap!" message that occasionally appears on Google Chrome? Does Chrome have an error log I can refer to? I'm suspecting this issue is caused by a recursive loop in the code which is then swallowing up all the memory? Is there any way I can confirm this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Aw, Snap!" why doesn't chrome work?](https://superuser.com/questions/382671/aw-snap-why-doesnt-chrome-work)

Comment: Related: [How to get more info when the “Aw Snap” screen shows up in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728483/55075)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is, see explanations here: for ordinary logging in Chrome, you could try:

- Use [Chrome's logging feature](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging):

  To enable logging, launch Chrome with these command line flags:

  `--enable-logging --v=1`

  The output will be saved to the file `chrome_debug.log` in [Chrome's user data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

  The location of the log file can be overridden by `CHROME_LOG_FILE` environment variable.

  For full list of flags, check: [Google Chrome command line switches](https://superuser.com/q/545033).
- Or use [the javascript console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console):

  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (Windows / Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd>+ <kbd>J</kbd> (Mac).

Comment: I think the first option will help isolate this problem. The dev console hangs before it can output anything of use.

Comment: I enabled the log and upon chrome crash, it didn't logged any error at the time of crash. Is there any reference that could provide insights into the log items?

Comment: Is this [chromium page about logging.h](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/logging.h) what you want?

Comment: Could you please include the abbreviated content of the links in this answer. It will go stale if the links die.

Comment: The Javascript console is usually not useful in this case, as the dev tools disconnect when the page crashes.

Comment: Same here. Chrome is generating aw snap, but nothing useful in the chrome_debug.log. I'm pretty sure it is running out of memory when the problem occurs, as it happens in a piece of code that loads a large number of images when generating a pdf.

Comment: @mafu it's a 700+lines git repository. I'm not sure how to abbreviate that, but if you can, please do.

Answer (score 37):

The offical Chrome Developers Twitter account [linked to a website](https://twitter.com/chromiumdev/status/119169013644394496) which helps you to debug the "Aw snap" pages: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

The recommendation is to launch Chrome with these flags:

`--enable-logging --v=1`

If you do that, then you can grab a crash log from the file `chrome_debug.log` in Chrome's user data directory (in the parent directory of `Default/`) or in the binary build folder (`out\Debug`) if you are using a debug build.

Comment: upvote because this post mentioned `--enable-logging --v=1`  long before the edit to the accepted answer added it.

Answer (score 5):

The *Aw, Snap!* page is usually related to process [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) crash which could be related to the [software bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug). To determine the cause, you can enable logging (as suggested in other answers) or analyse the backtrace of the core dump file (on [macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412156/55075), [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17965/55075), e.g. [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport)).

If you don't know the cause (e.g. stack trace consist only memory addresses), you can create a new support ticket at the [Chrome bug tracking system](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) (or double-check whether there is one already). While reporting, you should upload and include Crash ID by going to `chrome://crashes/` page, so memory addresses can be translated into debug symbols by the Chrome maintainers.

Alternatively you can [decode crash dumps](https://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps) yourself.

See also: [Where is Google Chrome Crash Dump Located?](https://superuser.com/q/624/87805)

---

To simplify above, here are the main reasons why the page can crash:

- You have found the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) (either on the website or with the web browser it-self).

  - Website bug

    - Example: JavaScript VM reached the maximum allocated memory (out-of-memory crash).

      To check that, run *DevTools* and check the *Memory* tab. If that's the case, the code should automatically pause just before the potential out-of-memory crash (e.g. [Issue 810015](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=810015)). If so, report the problem to the website owner, or profile the JS code to find the bug.
  - Browser bug

    - Consider disabling extensions or run in *Incognito* mode.
    - Consider removing [cached files](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392709).
    - [Report a bug](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines).
    - Re-install the browser.
    - Use a different version of Chrome such as [Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/), [Dev](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) or [Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html) channel.
    - Use different browser such as Epic, Firefox, Opera, Brave, Waterfox, Torch or other.
    - If issue is repeatable, you can try to re-compile [Chrome sources](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/#checking-out-and-building) with debug symbols and analyse the stack trace or report it.
- You've reached the maximum open files in your system (see: [#787381](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=787381)).

  On Linux/Unix/macOS, to verify that, run:

  ```
  sysctl -a | grep files
  ```

  and check whether `kern.num_files` reached the limit of `kern.maxfiles`.

  If that's the case, increase the limit by running the following commands:

  ```
  sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
  which launchctl && launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 unlimited
  which ulimit && ulimit -c unlimited
  ```
- You could have some malware/virus which alters your Chrome files causing the crash.
- You could have some [hardware memory-related issue](https://superuser.com/q/588247/87805). So run some test (such as `memtest`).

---

#### macOS

To display logs from Chrome, run:

```
log stream --level debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "Google"'
```

or by running *Console* app, where you can also check for any crash dumps (or check in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`). See: [Debug “Aw, Snap!” error in Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/1283240/87805)

---

#### Debugging

If none of above helps, you can consider [compiling Chrome from the source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/#checking-out-and-building) (takes a long time), then run directly from the Terminal. After that, each “Aw, Snap!” error should be followed by the full stack trace including functions and line in the source code file where it happened.

Answer (score 1):

On an Android where I did not have the startup logging flag option I found it useful to record a Performance Profile in the DevTools.

It showed me the last javascript function call made before the Aw Snap.

It turned out document.innerHtml threw an uncaught string allocation error of some sorts on a large div...

Comment: When the Aw Snap happens my dev tools disconnect and I lose my Performance Profile, how did you keep it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a web developer and I cant wait for all my customers to update Google Chrome, so..
We have been debugging this issue and founded a solution!

Seem to be a CSS simple-to-fix problem.
Seems that in some version of Chromes update's they have forbidden some html TAGs to have BEFORE and AFTER contents. One of this tags is Fieldset. Our team didnt find any other, but removing a fieldset:before{ content: ''; ... } solves the problem immeadiatly!

If you found any others TAGS please post it here. If you having the same problem, search your CSS code for :before and :after statements, should be easy to fix.

Recently added here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69161461/google-chrome-status-access-violation-error/69161462#69161462