# Debug "Aw, Snap!" error in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I studied [this](https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue) related question, but am still stumped.

I have an application that periodically shows the "Aw, Snap!" error screen, and to debug it, I have:

1. Launched Chrome with verbose logging enabled
2. Caused the tab to crash
3. Found the debug file (on Mac, ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/chrome_debug.log)
4. Examined the file for informative errors

But I haven't been able to find anything pertinent to the crash. Which is surprising. I expected some prominent `ERROR` level log entry with lots of details.

What would I expect to see in the log for an "Aw, Snap!" tab crash? Am I even looking in the right place? If not, where can I get crash details?

Comment: Having this exact problem. The diagnostics for this browser are worse than useless.

Comment: Also in the same boat. I don't think the browser logs are meant for debugging tab crashes. If I understand this correctly, then Chrome tabs are individual processes, which are just wrapped into a single Window. A tab crash is a proper application crash and needs to be debugged like any other native compiled program running into an exception. They just make it sound like it's a cute and harmless problem with that website, when it's really their browser falling apart.

Comment: Would love to learn from you if you discover a way to approach this, @Someone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the "Aw, Snap" dialogue](https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue)

Comment: @kenorb the first sentence of my post is a link to that question, and how it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If no error is found in the log file while running with [logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) (`--enable-logging --v=1`), try to run Chrome from the command-line, sometimes it should show more.

On macOS to display logs from Chrome, you can run this command:

```
log stream --level debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "Google"'
```

or by running *Console* app. If no error is shown, check for any crash dumps (location should be printed in the log). In *Console* app, crash files can be found under *User Reports* section (or directly in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` folder).

If you found related Chrome crash file, check which *Thread* crashed and find its stack trace, which can point to the cause.

If stack trace consists only memory addresses, you've two possibilities:

- Report the problem at [Chrome bug tracking system](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) including your uploaded local crash report ID (see: `chrome://crashes/`), so they can be translated by Chrome maintainers using debug symbols.
- [Compile Chrome from the source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/#checking-out-and-building) (takes a long time), then run directly from the *Terminal*. After that, each “Aw, Snap!” error should be followed by the full stack trace including functions and line in the source code file where it happened.

See also:

- [Chromium - How to enable logging?](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)
- [How to determine what is causing Chrome to show the "Aw, Snap" dialogue](https://superuser.com/q/607563/87805)
- [How to get more info when the “Aw Snap” screen shows up in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1728483/55075)

Comment: on Arch/Manjaro Linux you can see errors and stack traces with `journalctl --grep chrome`